# Internet Explorer readyState reverts from Complete to Interactive

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm submitting a form in IE and waiting for IE to return the results. However, I'm not having a consistent result across clients on my network. For me, it's consistent however.

The `readyState` reverts from `Complete` to `Interactive`. Why would it do that?

Code:

```
'submit form
ie_browser.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).submit
debug.print "Submitted form"

debug.print "Waiting for IE - 1 - readyState: " & ie_browser.readyState

Do While ie_browser.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
debug.print "Waiting for IE - 2 - readyState: " & ie_browser.readyState

Do Until ie_browser.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
debug.print "Waiting for IE - 3 - readyState: " & ie_browser.readyState

Do Until ie_browser.Busy = False: DoEvents: Loop
debug.print "Waiting for IE - 4 - readyState: " & ie_browser.readyState
```

Output:

```
Submitted form
Waiting for IE - 1 - readyState: 4
Waiting for IE - 2 - readyState: 3
```

**Edit #1**

For me:

```
Submitted form
Waiting for IE - 1 - readyState: 1
Waiting for IE - 2 - readyState: 1
Waiting for IE - 3 - readyState: 4
Waiting for IE - 4 - readyState: 4
```

**Edit #2**

Popup looks like this. It's using the `alert()` function.

[image]

**Edit #3**

My small test case:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As Object
    
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    'Hide and silence IE
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.Silent = True
    
    ie.navigate "http://127.0.0.1:9000/ftw/bad.html"
    Debug.Print "Navigated..."
    
    Debug.Print "Start wait..."
    Call waitForIE(ie)
    Debug.Print "End wait..."
        
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
    
    

End Sub

Public Sub waitForIE(i As InternetExplorer)
    'Craziest workaround ever due to bugged IE Eventhandling
    Do While i.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'popup occurred!
    If i.readyState = 3 Then
        Debug.Print "Popup! Stopped IE!"
        i.Stop
    Else
        Do Until i.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until i.Busy = False: DoEvents: Loop
        
        Debug.Print "Browser should have parsed and rendered the page at this time"
        
        Debug.Print "IE State: " & i.readyState & " IE busy: " & i.Busy
        
        'IE info
        Debug.Print "IE CompatMode: " & i.document.compatMode
        Debug.Print "IE DocumentMode: " & i.document.documentMode
    End If
    
End Sub
```

HTML with popup (based off the platform I'm querying):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Bad file</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
Bad!
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Hello World!");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit #4

When I pick up the popup, I kill IE instead:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As Object
    
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    'Hide and silence IE
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.Silent = True
    
    ie.navigate "http://127.0.0.1:9000/ftw/bad.html"
    Debug.Print "Navigated..."
    
    Debug.Print "Start wait..."
    Call waitForIE(ie)
    Debug.Print "End wait..."
        
    'close if found
    If Not ie Is Nothing Then
        ie.Quit
        Set ie = Nothing
    End If
    
    

End Sub

Public Sub waitForIE(i As InternetExplorer)
    'Craziest workaround ever due to bugged IE Eventhandling
    Do While i.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'popup occurred!
    If i.readyState = 3 Then
        Debug.Print "Popup! Killed IE!"
        i.Stop
        i.Quit
        Set i = Nothing
    Else
        Do Until i.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until i.Busy = False: DoEvents: Loop
        
        Debug.Print "Browser should have parsed and rendered the page at this time"
        
        Debug.Print "IE State: " & i.readyState & " IE busy: " & i.Busy
        
        'IE info
        Debug.Print "IE CompatMode: " & i.document.compatMode
        Debug.Print "IE DocumentMode: " & i.document.documentMode
    End If
    
End Sub
```

However, I do get some popups that sneak by:

[image]

**Edit #5**

Apparently, killing IE doesn't really kill it. I see multiple instances in Task Manager. I have to bring them to the foreground to see the popup and click the button to close the popup to see the process go away.

**Edit #6**

I found a function that loops to close all IE instances (IE_Sledgehammer), but like the last poster, my function hangs too:

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/close-all-ie-browser-windows-with-vba.229394/

**Edit #7**

I've been experimenting with the function `KillHwndProcess` found here:
https://www.devhut.net/2018/09/09/vba-forcing-applications-to-close/

```
If i.readyState = 3 Then
    Debug.Print "Popup!"
    ie_hwnd = i.hwnd
    Debug.Print "ie_hwnd: " & ie_hwnd
    i.Quit
    Set i = Nothing
    Debug.Print "Quit IE, set to nothing..."
    Call KillHwndProcess(ie_hwnd)
    Debug.Print "Killed IE process..."
Then
```

Comment: It would appear a popup window would revert the readyState back to 3. I tried on my side with IE visible and that's what occurred. Will need to add extra logic to counter this.

Comment: So the pop-up only occurs on certain machines?

Comment: If possible, then you can post the snapshot of the popup window. We can try to provide suggestions for handling that popup.

Comment: @QHarr Yes. The popup is due to the platform running out of licenses (or an actual bad password, which I have collected in previous steps) and throwing out an authentication error. Once the pool is refreshed, by having old sessions die out, it works again. There are no plans to get more licenses, unfortunately.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT see Edit #2

Comment: Can you see the JS function that shows this popup in the source code of the webpage? If yes, can you share some code about that? We can try to test whether we can add some JS code that closes the alert by itself.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT it's a simple alert()... I added Edit #7 with the latest thing I'm trying, that looks like it could work.

Comment: I tested the code that you had mentioned in `Edit#7` but on my side, it also gets stuck until we close the alert manually. What I was talking about in my previous comment is to override the JS code by setting the new JS code that does not contain alert() for the control attribute that calls function. something like this ` `ie.document.getElementById("btn1").setAttribute "onclick", "JS code or function without alert()"`. By doing this, you can perform the same operation but without alert(). So no need to quit IE instance. You can test on your side and let us know about the results.

Comment: Thanks for checking. This was my using a test case that I was trying to debug with. The remote website that I'm calling in my production application isn't under my control thus I cannot change the output. This is a legacy app for my organization which is only ensured to be running until it's replaced at some point.

Comment: Other than that I did not get any solution or workaround for the said issue. If you are available to use the Selenium IE web driver to automate the IE browser then there you can handle alert() properly.

Comment: Oh man, I forgot a huge detail in my post. This is done in Excel VBA! I did select the tag, but failed to mention it in the post. My bad!

Comment: Yes, I know you are doing the VBA IE automation in Excel. I was talking about other possibilities in case you are available to check it out.